# Difference between Apache directive vs Apache modules

Tags: php, apache, server

I am confused with these 2 terms Apache directive , Apache modules.Are they same or different?

Comment: Directive is a "command" that you place in a .conf file (`DirectoryIndex` for example). A module is a shared object (.so) compiled beforehand that extends Apache functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `module` is a piece of code that resides in a library (a file) that is dynamically loaded by a program. The module integrates into the program and extends its functionality.

A `directive` is an entry (a line or a block of text) in a configuration file.

For example, the [`LoadModule` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_so.html#loadmodule) tells Apache to load a module (Apache does not decide by itself when to load a module and what modules to load; other programs have other rules.)